# jQuery .prop() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out why this isn't working. I am trying select either a warehouse or a salesman which are stored in 2 separate select inputs, and when you click one input, the other input disables.

The link is to reset the select back to enabled since I can't figure out how to do it aside from "faking" the CSS to make it look disabled. Any help/explanation is greatly appreciated. It's very crude I apologize, I'm learning.

Codepen specifically - http://codepen.io/BrandonSM/pen/bdjjrZ/

jQuery

HTML

```
    <select id="select_warehouse">
      <option value="chicago">Chicago</option>
      <option value="toronto">Toronto</option>
      <option value="fort-wayne">Fort Wayne</option>
    </select> <a href="#" id="#link_warehouse">CHOOSE WAREHOUSE</a>
    <br><br>or<br><br>
     <select id="select_salesman">
      <option value="james">James</option>
      <option value="chris">Chris</option>
      <option value="shawn">Shawn</option>
    </select> <a href="#" id="#link_salesman">CHOOSE SALESMAN</a>`
```

jQuery code:

```
    $("#select_salesman").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#select_warehouse").prop('disabled', true);
    });


    $("#link_warehouse").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#select_warehouse").prop('disabled', false);
    });

    $("#select_warehouse").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#select_salesman").prop('disabled', true);
    });

    $("#link_salesman").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#select_salesman").prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

Comment: You should not use click with select....

Comment: Could you explain why specifically @epascarello ? Should I instead use .bind() and bind the function to the object?

Comment: You should be using change or blur

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<a href="#" id="#link_warehouse">CHOOSE WAREHOUSE</a>
<a href="#" id="#link_salesman">CHOOSE SALESMAN</a>
```

into

```
<a href="#" id="link_warehouse">CHOOSE WAREHOUSE</a>
<a href="#" id="link_salesman">CHOOSE SALESMAN</a>
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/metallurgical/pen/xGQLwE)** -- is it like this you want?

Comment: I knew it was something ridiculous. Thanks @Norlihazmey Ghazali

Comment: @Brandon Yeah, the original implementation was for html bookmark, but in this case we won't `#` inside id attribute as we already implement using jquery click event. Anyway, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#link_warehouse").click(function() {
 $("#select_warehouse").prop('disabled', false);
  $("#select_salesman").prop('disabled', true);   
});

$("#link_salesman").click(function() {
  $("#select_salesman").prop('disabled', false);
  $("#select_warehouse").prop('disabled', true);  
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mahima154/j2nvkabw/